# Django select users from seperate model

Tags: django, model

I have two models:

```
class PlayerPermissionGroup(models.Model):
  player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PlayerPermissionGroupMember(models.Model):
  permission_group = models.ForeignKey(PlayerPermissionGroup)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Currently, to get all the member in a Permissions Group I do:

```
getMembers(group):
  group_member_ids = (PlayerPermissionGroupMember.objects.filter(permission_group=group)
                                                         .values_list('user__id'))
  return User.objects.filter(pk__in=group_member_ids)
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MAY add a `related_name` to you FK to `User`:

```
class PlayerPermissionGroupMember(models.Model):
  permission_group = models.ForeignKey(PlayerPermissionGroup)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='player_permision_groups')
```

Then you can do:

```
getMembers(group):
  return User.objects.filter(player_permision_groups__permission_group=group)
```

You may omit the `related_name` but the lookup changes slightly by using the default `related_name` that django assigns instead.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I'm looking for! I'm assuming this just does the inner query for you then on the sql side?

Comment: Yes, as you might know, queries in django are lazy, so you can chain methods like `distinct`, `values`, `values_list`, etc and a single sql query will be constructed at the end :)